# Trouble evaluating a piece-wise series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm having a hard time understanding what this sequence of functions is doing. This is a problem in my textbook for undergrad analysis.

\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{n} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: It's not doing anything. It just exists. What is the  problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hard time seeing how this sequence looks like, try plugging in the first few values of $n$:

\begin{equation}
f_1(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_2(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 1,\frac{1}{2}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_3(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_4(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

In other words, $f_n$ is a function that is zero everywhere besides at $n$ points (namely at $1, \frac{1}{2},... \frac{1}{n}$), where it takes the value $1$.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that each $f_n$ is not continuous at zero?

Comment: thank you by the way, So the functions is a bunch of points rational and irrational on the interval $(0,1]$?

Comment: You don't have to "assume" anything. Each $f_n$ is discontinuous at $0.$ Also, I am not sure what you mean by " functions is a bunch of points rational and irrational on the interval..." Each $f_n$ takes only two values, namely $0$ and $1.$